# Import Woocommerce CSV with Variable products and equal SKU's

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I exported a CSV form another Woocommerce site. This CSV has a lot of the same SKU,s
When I import this CSV I get an error. Cannot import because of the same SKU's

I tried this code: `add_filter( 'wc_product_has_unique_sku', '__return_false' );`
But this doesn't work either.

I only have to do this once.
So my question is:

Is it possible to change a core Woocommerce file once, that checks for equal SKU's while importing?
And change it back when the import is done?

Does anybody know which Woocommerce file I have to edit, and which code I have to edit?